# How to handle waiting status in ODI

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I use ***Limit Concurrent Executions option* to handle concurrent executions for Load plan.** If there is a load plan running, the Limit Concurrent Executions option cause a Waiting status for others then kill them by an Error.
**Is there a way to handle the waiting status and send an alert email?**